# Javascript nested filters in Array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array of objects in this format:

```
var full_list = [
        {
            "pid": 1,
            "items":[
                {"item_id": '9'},
                {"item_id": '10'},
                {"item_id": '12'}
            ]
        },
        {
            "pid": 2,
            "items":[
                {"item_id": '33'},
                {"item_id": '22'},
                {"item_id": '65'}
            ]
        }...
    ];
```

I have a tmp array which consists of objects from the full array:

```
 var tmp_list =  [
        {
            "pid": 2,
            "items":[
                {"item_id": '33'},
                {"item_id": '22'},
                {"item_id": '65'}
            ]
        }, {....}
```

I would like to filter out objects from the full list where at least one of selectedIDs values appears in the object's item's id array

```
var selectedIDs = {'1', '9', '45', ....};
```

and then add them to the tmp list.

I tried using filters but I failed to figure it out completely.

Thank you.

```
selectedIDs.forEach(function(id) {
                var tmp = full_list.filter(function (obj) {
                            obj.items.forEach(function (item) {
                                if (item.id === id) {
                                    console.log('found');
                                }
                            });
                        });
                        tmp_list.push(tmp);
                 });
```

Comment: Do you have the option to use libraries like lodash etc? Issues like these there are solved quite nicely.

Comment: Is it possible some already exist in temp list? Current answers would create duplicates if so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, this line in your question is wrong

var selectedIDs = {'1', '9', '45', ....};

You cannot declare arrays using `{}`. Instead use `[]`

For your problem you can use a **pure functional approach** using **Array#filter** and **Array#some** methods to get your desired result as below:

```js
var full_list = [
  {
    "pid": 1,
    "items":[
      {"item_id": '9'},
      {"item_id": '10'},
      {"item_id": '12'}
    ]
  },
  {
    "pid": 2,
    "items":[
      {"item_id": '33'},
      {"item_id": '22'},
      {"item_id": '67'}
    ]
  },
  {
    "pid": 9,
    "items":[
      {"item_id": '33'},
      {"item_id": '22'},
      {"item_id": '65'}
    ]
  },
  {
    "pid": 7,
    "items":[
      {"item_id": '7'},
      {"item_id": '22'},
      {"item_id": '65'}
    ]
  }
];

var tmp_list = [
  {
    "pid": 2,
    "items":[
      {"item_id": '7'},
      {"item_id": '22'},
      {"item_id": '65'}
    ]
  }
];


function filterResult (selectedItems) {
  return full_list.filter(function (process) {
    return process.items.some(function(item){
      return selectedItems.indexOf(item.item_id) > -1;
    });
  });
}

var selectedItems = ['9', '7', '22', '10'];

tmp_list = tmp_list.concat(filterResult(selectedItems))

console.log(tmp_list);


function flattenResults(list, selections) {
  return list.reduce(function (accumulator, current) {
    var res = current.items.filter(function(item){
      return (selections.indexOf(item.item_id) > -1 
              && checkIfAlreadyExist());
              
      function checkIfAlreadyExist () {
        return accumulator.every(function (k) {
          return k.item_id !== item.item_id;
        });
      }        
    });   

    return accumulator.concat(res);
  }, []);
}

console.log(flattenResults(full_list, selectedItems));
```

Comment: honestly, I don't understand those nested 'return's, but it worked flawlessly. thanks.

Comment: For understanding them refer the MDN documentation for `Array.filter` and `Array.some` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: @badigard: Also if the solution works for you please accept it so that others don't have to explore further for the solution of same/ similar problem

Comment: done. another small Q: how do I modify this code so it will return the {item_id: 'x'} object it found?

Comment: Do you mean only list of the found `{item_id: 'x'}` objects but not the whole object containing `pid, items`?

Comment: yes, exactly. and please exclude duplicates. If it make the performance better - once 1 object found, no need to iterate over other items.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115703/discussion-between-aditya-singh-and-badigard).

Answer (score 4):

You may do like this;

```js
var full_list = [
        {
            "pid": 1,
            "items":[
                {"item_id": '9'},
                {"item_id": '10'},
                {"item_id": '12'}
            ]
        },
        {
            "pid": 2,
            "items":[
                {"item_id": '33'},
                {"item_id": '22'},
                {"item_id": '65'}
            ]
        }
],
  selectedIDs = ['1', '9', '45'],
     tempList = [];
tempList.push(full_list.filter(f => f.items.some(o => selectedIDs.includes(o.item_id))));
console.log(tempList);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a hash table for the selectedID and use it for fast filtering.

```js
var full_list = [{ "pid": 1, "items": [{ "item_id": '9' }, { "item_id": '10' }, { "item_id": '12' }] }, { "pid": 2, "items": [{ "item_id": '33' }, { "item_id": '22' }, { "item_id": '65' }] }],
    tmp_list,
    selectedIDs = ['1', '9', '45'],
    selected = Object.create(null);

selectedIDs.forEach(function (a) {
    selected[a] = true;
});

tmp_list = full_list.filter(function (a) {
    return !a.items.some(function (b) {
        return selected[b.item_id];
    });
});

console.log(tmp_list);
```

ES6

```js
var full_list = [{ "pid": 1, "items": [{ "item_id": '9' }, { "item_id": '10' }, { "item_id": '12' }] }, { "pid": 2, "items": [{ "item_id": '33' }, { "item_id": '22' }, { "item_id": '65' }] }],
    tmp_list,
    selectedIDs = ['1', '9', '45'],
    selected = Object.create(null);

selectedIDs.forEach(a => selected[a] = true);
tmp_list = full_list.filter(a => !a.items.some(b=> selected[b.item_id]));

console.log(tmp_list);
```

Comment: You made it wrong. you must check of the item_id is in `selectedIDs`.

Comment: i use a hash table `selected` and the check appears here: `!a.items.some(function (b) { return selected[b.item_id]; });`.

Comment: That would be the best answer if it returns the correct answer. but non of selected ids are in returned value

Comment: sorry, that is not right, it should filter **out** where some of `item_id` appears in `selectedIDs`.

Answer (score 3):

```
array1
array2

array1.filter(el=>{
   return array2.filter(el2=>{
          return el.id == el2.id
     })
})
```

It will take array1 and run it against the second one ... for each value.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a solution.

```js
var full_list = [
  { 
    "pid": 1, 
    "items": [
    { "item_id": '9' }, 
    { "item_id": '10' }, 
    { "item_id": '12' }
  ]
}, {
  "pid": 2,
  "items": [{
    "item_id": '33'
  }, {
    "item_id": '22'
  }, {
    "item_id": '65'
  }]
}];

var selectedIDs = ['33', '3'];
var tempList = [];

full_list
  .filter(item => 
    item.items
      .some(i => selectedIDs.indexOf(i.item_id) != -1)
   ).forEach(item => tempList.push(item));
console.log(tempList)
```

Answer (score -2):

Looking at your job
1. There is nothing like `market`

`obj.items.forEach(function (item) {`
                               `if (item.item_id === id) {`
                                    `console.log('found');`
                                      `return true;`
                            `}`
                             `return false;`
                            `});`

Comment: where does `forEach` return to?

Answer (score -2):

`Spread operator` should simplify some code:

```js
var full_list = [
  { 
    "pid": 1, 
    "items": [
    { "item_id": '9' }, 
    { "item_id": '10' }, 
    { "item_id": '12' }
  ]
}, {
  "pid": 2,
  "items": [{
    "item_id": '33'
  }, {
    "item_id": '22'
  }, {
    "item_id": '65'
  }]
}];

var selectedIDs = ['65', '6'];
var tempList = [];

tempList = [...tempList, 
            ...full_list.filter(item => item.items.some(i => selectedIDs.includes(i.item_id)))
           ];

console.log(tempList);
```

Comment: @mortezaT why redundant? It's necessary for destructuring the two list into new one. I think it's equivalent to the approach with Array.concat() method but with this new operator, that makes it more readable, unless for me.  =)

Comment: None of the above will append to `tempList`.

Comment: I don't get you! The OP says: "I would like to filter out objects from the full list where at least one of selectedIDs values appears in the object's item's id array and then add them to the tmp list."  That's exactly what I'm doing...

Comment: The exact part which saying `and then add them to the tmp list.`

Comment: then the example of `tmp_list` makes no sense.